# hasManyThrough query without laravel_through_key

Tags: laravel, eloquent

With a Laravel hasManyThrough relationship how can I prevent extra keys added to the select? Is there a withoutPivot or simiar?

I'm trying to perform a union join and need to the columns to be the same.

SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS aggregate
FROM ((
        SELECT
            `order_payments`.`id`,
            `order_payments`.*,
            `orders`.`user_id` AS `laravel_through_key`
        FROM
            `order_payments`
            INNER JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`id` = `order_payments`.`order_id`
        WHERE
            `orders`.`user_id` = 1)
    UNION (
        SELECT
            `orders`.`id`
        FROM
            `orders`
        WHERE
            `orders`.`user_id` = 1
            AND `orders`.`user_id` IS NOT NULL)) AS `temp_table`
```

I'm unable to use the makeHidden as suggested in another question

```
$payments = auth()->user()->orderPayments()->select('order_payments.id');

$orders = auth()->user()->orders()->select('orders.id');

$payments->union($orders)->paginate(50);
```

I guess I could do it without Eloquent manually but just wondering if there was another way?

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements UserContract {
    /**
     * Orders for this User
     */
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    /**
     * Order Payments for this User
     */
    public function orderPayments()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(OrderPayment::class, Order::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm also wondering how to do this, just found this question which matches my problem too- using Unions. Did you find a solution?